# JQuery JQGrid plugin, how to simulate a toolbar filter operation by link click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

I'm using JQuery and JqGrid plugin with filter tool bar. For example, when input "ABC" in the filter of column "Name", all the name contains "ABC" will be filtered.

Now, I hope that when I click a link like below:

```
<a href="???">ABC</a>
```

all the names contains "ABC" will be filtered, just like the filter toolbar operations.

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you want to place the link `<a href="???">ABC</a>`?

In general you need to place a button, a link, a span or some other element on the page and to bind `click` event which calls `triggerToolbar()` and return false to prevent default action of `<a>`. Thus the solution could be the following HTML code

```html
<a id="mysearch" href="#">Click me to apply the filter</a>
```

and the following JavaScript code

```js
$("#mysearch").click(function () {
    $("#mygrid")[0].triggerToolbar();
    return false;
});
```